# Understanding EF Core SQL query translation

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-7.0

I have questions, regarding EF Core translation, is this query already optimized?

```
SELECT
    e."EmployeeId",
    e."PositionId",
    t."Name"
FROM
    "Employee" AS e
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         m."PositionId",
         m."Name"
     FROM
         "MasterPosition" AS m
     WHERE
         NOT (m."IsDeleted")) AS t ON e."PositionId" = t."PositionId"
```

Same as this?

```
SELECT
    e."EmployeeId",
    e."PositionId",
    MP."Name" as "PositionName"
FROM
    "Employee" e
INNER JOIN
    public."MasterPosition" MP ON MP."PositionId" = e."PositionId"
WHERE
    NOT e."IsDeleted"
```

I am a little bit confused about the `INNER JOIN (SELECT)` part, do they get all masterPosition, then filter, or is it just syntactic sugar?

Comment: run a query plan on both and compare

Comment: Does it really matter whether it is the same? You're not going to change how EF translates LINQ into SQL. Frankly, I'm wondering what you want with this question.

Comment: Second query do not take in account `m."IsDeleted"`

Answer (score -1):

Both queries are equivalent in terms of functionality, and the decision as to which is more effective is primarily dependent upon the particular database engine and its query optimizer. In reality, the database engine ought to be able to optimize both queries for similar performance. As a result, you can select the query form that is easier to comprehend and maintain for your code and leave optimization to the database engine.

Comment: You're not really saying much here. "the database engine ought to be able to optimize...". Yeah, of course. "you can select the query form that is easier to comprehend". This is not about selecting a query. Not that it's clear what the question is about, but surely not about selecting a query for EF to generate. As the first comment says: look at the query plan. That's all there is to it. We can't do that for OP.